# SolrClean isn't deleting from Solr

Tags: solr, nutch, solr4

When I run Nutch and a link is no longer present, I can run the `readdb` command and it shows me that there are urls marked as `db_gone`.

So I run the SolrClean command and it says:

```
SolrClean deleting a total of 1 documents
```

Which is correct, but nothing is removed from Solr

Help?

If you want to check my configuration then I have a blog with how my own Solr/Nutch set-up is configured [Here](http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html)

***Edit***:

There is a good chance it is not just the SolrClean command that isnt working, I have a feeling it is something to do with my set-up where deletes arent being committed?

This is the delete request issued for the document - yet the document exists:

```
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:52.729; 
org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2} 
{delete=file:/C:/Users/alamil/Documents/TextFiles/Y2012.doc 
(-1442903587791306752)]} 0 2
```

This is the whole log:

```
 INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:51.785; org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher; Opening Searcher@f5331a main
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:51.786; org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener; QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@f5331a main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_7w:549:nrt _6j(4.3.1):C12/11 _6k(4.3.1):C12)}
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:51.787; org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener; QuerySenderListener done.
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:51.787; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; end_commit_flush
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:51.788; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@f5331a main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_7w:549:nrt _6j(4.3.1):C12/11 _6k(4.3.1):C12)}
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:51.789; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={waitSearcher=true&commit=true&wt=javabin&waitFlush=true&version=2} {commit=} 0 903
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:52.053; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select params={fl=id&q=id:[*+TO+*]&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=1} hits=13 status=0 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:52.355; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select params={fl=id&q=id:[*+TO+*]&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=1} hits=13 status=0 QTime=0 
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:52.413; org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/select params={fl=id,boost,tstamp,digest&start=0&q=id:[*+TO+*]&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=13} hits=13 status=0 QTime=1 
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:52.729; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2} {delete=[file:/C:/Users/alamil/Documents/TextFiles/Y2012.doc (-1442903587791306752)]} 0 2
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:52.733; org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2; start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:52.835; org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy; SolrDeletionPolicy.onCommit: commits:num=2
commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory@C:\Users\alamil\Documents\Test\solr_home\data\index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@1ae0e7d; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_7w,generation=284,filenames=[_6j_1.del, _6k_Lucene41_0.pos, segments_7w, _6j.nvd, _6j_Lucene41_0.tim, _6j_Lucene41_0.tip, _6k.fdt, _6k.fnm, _6j_Lucene41_0.pos, _6j.nvm, _6k_Lucene41_0.doc, _6k_Lucene41_0.tim, _6k.si, _6j.si, _6k.nvd, _6k.fdx, _6j_Lucene41_0.doc, _6j.fdt, _6k.nvm, _6j.fdx, _6k_Lucene41_0.tip, _6j.fnm]
commit{dir=NRTCachingDirectory(org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory@C:\Users\alamil\Documents\Test\solr_home\data\index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@1ae0e7d; maxCacheMB=48.0 maxMergeSizeMB=4.0),segFN=segments_7x,generation=285,filenames=[_6j_1.del, _6k_Lucene41_0.pos, _6j.nvd, _6j_Lucene41_0.tim, _6j_Lucene41_0.tip, _6k.fdt, _6k.fnm, _6j_Lucene41_0.pos, _6j.nvm, _6k_Lucene41_0.doc, _6k_Lucene41_0.tim, _6k.si, _6j.si, _6k.nvd, _6k.fdx, segments_7x, _6j_Lucene41_0.doc, _6j.fdt, _6k.nvm, _6j.fdx, _6k_Lucene41_0.tip, _6j.fnm]
INFO  - 2013-08-09 15:54:52.835; org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy; newest commit = 285[_6j_1.del, _6k_Lucene41_0.pos, _6j.nvd, _6j_Lucene41_0.tim, _6j_Lucene41_0.tip, _6k.fdt, _6k.fnm, _6j_Lucene41_0.pos, _6j.nvm, _6k_Lucene41_0.doc, _6k_Lucene41_0.tim, _6k.si, _6j.si, _6k.nvd, _6k.fdx, segments_7x, _6j_Lucene41_0.doc, _6j.fdt, _6k.nvm, _6j.fdx, _6k_Lucene41_0.tip, _6j.fnm]
```

Comment: My guess is that the change isn't `commited`, I know [there was](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1000) a ticket to make commit as an option

Comment: There is no flag to commit the action so if it doesnt commit it, I have no idea how I would

Answer (score 1):

Take dump of crawldb and find urls with status db_gone and check for these urls in solr index. If you are doing fresh crawl you wont find any of these urls in your Solr index as db_gone urls are not considered for indexing.

Now when we run solrclean command nutch finds all the urls with status db_gone in crawldb and deletes all these urls from Solr index. If any url with status db_gone found in solr index then only index will be changed otherwise index will remain unchanged.

This may be happening in your case.

Note: 
In case of re-crawl only we may find out some urls which already crawled and indexed successfully during first crawling but marked as db_gone in re-crawl phase as these urls are not available anymore. So these urls will be deleted from solr index when we run solrclean command and solr index will be changed.

Have a look into source code of SolrClean class.
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.nutch/nutch/1.3/org/apache/nutch/indexer/solr/SolrClean.java

Hope helped you....

Comment: Yeah, I understand how the SolrClean command works, looking for urls with status DB_GONE and deleting those documents from Solr.  The problem is not maybe so much with the SolrClean command but maybe my setup isnt allowing the deletion to happen, because it recognises that there is 1 document to delete

Comment: Nutch selects 1 document to delete from crawl_db only, it wont check solr index whether document presents in solr index or not. If selected document does not present in solr index nothing will be deleted. But you can find a log showing "SolrClean: deleting 1 documents". This log doesn't always mean that 1 document will be deleted from Solr index. If document present in solr index then only it will be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, The thing is that document is definatley in Solr.  I checked the log and looked at the delete request it issues and it is for a document present in the Solr index

Comment: Can you share ur solr log after running SolrClean.